# When making a dataclass, how can I use a custom type for the field objects themselves?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I'm writing a library that works a lot like `dataclass` but with some additional functionality. Obviously I want to reuse `dataclass` as much as possible, but for my added functionality, I'd like to extend `dataclass.Field`. That is, I'd like to define:

```
class MyField(dataclasses.Field):
  ... # additional functionality
```

And then do *something* so that when the user does:

```
@mydataclass
class UserDefinedClass:
  foo: int
  y: Bar
```

(Where `mydataclass` is a decorator that eventually calls `dataclass`...)

The actual field objects inside `UserDefinedClass` will be of type `MyField` rather than `dataclasses.Field`.

I can't find anything in the dataclass docs that allows me to do this, but I think I might be missing something.

(I am aware of the `metadata` keyword argument to `field`, and I will probably use that if the answer to this question is "that's impossible". But it'll be more work.)

Comment: "there doesn't seem to be any reason to make the `Field` type public"... how would you do `isinstance(..., dataclasses.Field)` if it wasn't public?

Comment: Fair enough. Deleted that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly doesn't exactly look as though `dataclasses.Field` is supposed to be subclassed, and convincing the `dataclass` decorator to use a custom field is, well, a bit grotesque, but this works – even if I'd advise against this.

It would certainly be nicer if you could tell `dataclass()` to use a custom `field` class, but alas...

```
import dataclasses
from unittest import mock


def mydataclass(**kwargs):
    def deco(cls):
        with mock.patch("dataclasses.Field", MyField):  # NB: not thread-safe
            return dataclasses.dataclass(**kwargs)(cls)

    return deco


class MyField(dataclasses.Field):
    def honk(self):
        print(
            f"You hear {self.name!r} the {self.type.__name__} emitting a loud HONK!"
        )


@mydataclass()
class MyData:
    a: int
    b: str


d = MyData(1, "hello")
for f in dataclasses.fields(d):
    f.honk()
```

This prints out

```
You hear 'a' the int emitting a loud HONK!
You hear 'b' the str emitting a loud HONK!
```

as you might imagine.